# how do I find the element number of the minimum value of a 1d array

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, element

I know how to find the minimum value of an array using the min function, but I'm unsure of how to locate the element number using a function

```
function [m,r]= RightMin(a1)
% m gives the minimum value in the 1d array given
m=min(a1);
% linearindices is supposed to name the element number of the minimum value found.
linearindices = find(a1==m) ;
r=linearindices;
end
```

so if the array was a=[4,7,67,9,34,1,6,87,5,34]
then m=1
but r should be 6
r=6 because the minimum number 1 is in the sixth elemental position in the array.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) is a really good way to figuring out how to do things. Especially for MATLAB, whose documentation is superb.

Answer (score 2):

You can request the index from the min() function.

Example:

```
[m, r] = min(a1);
```